# Can we force Chrome browser to be at an expecting state in the Selenium tests with the web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Again I request and need your help.

I'm testing a graphical element, for that, I'm taking screen shots of the graph. One is the expectation and the other one is the current graphic in the chrome browser. 
We are running this test in different windows.

My issue is : the windows can have another resolution or another chrome version installed. If there is a diff configuration, then, my two screen shots will be differents because I'm comparing them **pixel by pixel**, and, my test will fail.

My question is : there is a way to force or emulate chrome to have the same text size, version, ...

Thanks

Comment: **1.**  This is inherently a very very flaky scenario for UI testing.  Comparing anything pixel by pixel will be so.



**2.**  Your windows are opening different versions of chrome??  Do you have more than one chromedriver?  Is that intentional?

**3.**  As far as screen resolution you can use the following to set the screen to have a width of 1300 pixels and a height of 1000 pixels, or whatever you might want.

`ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1300,1000");`

You would have to do this before you define the browser/driver.

Comment: U can force chrome browser to set its height & width using something like this `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280,776));` . This way you will be sure that whatever screenshot captured is captured with given height & width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
For your point : 2. It's multiple windows, we are not using only one machine to test, so the chrome can be different based on the client side. I have only one chromedriver, defined in the pom.xml. 3.I'm already setting this as argument

driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280,776)); this is working to resize the browser but not helpful if the text display changed
thanks for your help